# Should my Super User question be migrated to Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, migration

I asked [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/710495/is-it-possible-to-run-corona-sdk-on-reactos-or-wine).

Is it on topic here or not? If yes (and migrated), what will happen to the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question itself is a bit borderline, but I'm leaning toward on-topic. However, asking "What OS will run *program*" isn't on-topic on any SE site that I know of.

You might be able to get a moderator to refund the bounty before a migration, but most likely it will just disappear into nothingness.

Comment: `The question itself is a bit borderline` I know, that's why I asked on meta to make sure :) `What OS will run program" isn't on-topic.` So Will it be voted down and closed? And btw, I'm not asking for refund, can I migrate the existing bounty to here?

Comment: @Fischer That part would have to be removed from the question, yes. And no, you can't migrate bounties.

Comment: Okay then, I'll wait till my bounty expires, if I get no answer there, I'll remove that part and ask for a migration